# Update column based on select from another table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

Im traying to update a table based on a slect from another table. Both tables have in common the name coll.

so the idea is grom hitorial to get the min price of each name, and update those to every row in names that mactch the name.

I have tried several examples found here, but none did the trick.

This is the inner select

```
SELECT name, MIN(price) FROMhistorial group by name
```

this should update a

```
UPDATE names set MIN_PRICE = min_price_from_select WHERE name = name_from_select
```

result should be, the table Names updated with the min prices from historial.

Comment: "*so the idea is grom hitorial*"???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [join an `UPDATE` statement with a `FROM` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html). In your case:

```
UPDATE names
SET min_price = q.min_price
FROM (
  SELECT name, MIN(price) as min_price
  FROM historical
  GROUP BY name
) as q
WHERE name = q.name
```

The alternative would be a subselect, but that would also try to update *all* `names`, not only those that exist in `historical`:

```
UPDATE names
SET min_price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM historical WHERE historical.name = names.name)
```